# how to get Pending Transactions by specified address ethereum?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Could you help me please? I tried almost everything.

I tried this:

```js
var options = {
  fromBlock: "pending",
  toBlock: "latest",
  address: "0xabc123...",
}

web3.eth.filter(options, (error, result) => {
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

but it returned nothing
also I tried with `eth.subscribe` but it returned every pending transactions

Answer (score 1):

You can search for transactions in the pending block using getBlock and loop through the transactions id from the result. Do check the docs for a sample output.

```
web3.eth.getBlock("pending")
```

If you know your transaction id, you can immediately use getTransactionReceipt

```
web3.eth.getTransaction( {transaction id} )
```

But if you are searching by sender or receiver address, then u may need to getTransactionReceipt from the transaction id of pending block.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getblock

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction